# Jupyter Notebook not able to execute shutil.make_archive() ........what should I do?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, shutil

I am getting an asterisk in front of the cell after I execute the cell ....Following is my code:

```
import shutil

dir_to_zip='C:\\Users\\ASUS'

output_filename='example'   


shutil.make_archive(output_filename,'zip',dir_to_zip)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know what Shutil does but I know a bit of Jupyter Notebook

I have 2 potential reasons :

- Your function is creating an infinite loop (which, in your case, might not be the reason since the function is not yours, but from a module)
- Your Kernel died : In some versions of Jupyter Notebook, you have no message when your kernel dies and the hourglass just disappear. In this case : First try to clean your memory using Kernel > Restart Kernel and Clear All Outputs on all your recent executed codes. If it's not enough and kernel keeps on dying, then try to logout and allow more memory on your server (if possible)

There might have many other reasons, but I haven't been coding for a long on Jupyter so I might not find them all

Comment: I tried restarting the kernel, but nothing changes. Besides, my code is exactly same as my udemy instructor. It didn't have any problem with his code.

Comment: Besides, shutil module allows the users to copy, paste files in the program.

Comment: Does the hourglass stays or it end ups disappearing even though the "In[*]" is still there ?

Comment: Its state is exactly as  same as the one in the image. Nothing has changed since.

Comment: It was indeed running an indefinite loop ,since when I asked this question, there was approximately 45 GB space available on my c drive. But just now, I saw that the file occupied almost all of the remaining space on my drive!!